fmin (scipy) and understanding parameter passing of the function in python
I've been trying to understand the parameter passing of fmin.
This is given for our exercise:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.optimize import fsolve, fmin
from scipy.misc import derivative
from numpy import array

MU = 1.3
SIGMA = 4.5
N = 1000
N_BINS=20

data = np.random.normal(MU, SIGMA, N)
#print(data)

Definition of the normal function (seems to work judging by the plot):
def normalpdf(x,mu,sigma): 
    return ((1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)))*(np.exp(-(((x-mu)**2))/(2*sigma**2))))

plt.plot(data, normalpdf(data,MU,SIGMA),'.', color='purple')

Definition of the likelihood function (not sure it's correct, see note below with an alternative of another student's version, I do get a plot, so technically it's a working function):
def vect_q():
    q=[MU,SIGMA]
    return q

Logln=0
def LogL(q):
    return  Logln + (- np.log(normalpdf(data,q[0],q[1])))` 

#q=vect_q()
#result_LogL=LogL(q)
#print (result_LogL)       
                   
#LnL=sorted(LogL(q))
#plt.plot(LnL)

This is the block with the fmin that doesn't work. See all I have tried with the different error messages further down.
x0 = 1
q=vect_q
minimum = fmin(LogL,x0,(q[0],q[1]))
print(minimum)

What I've tried:
I search for fmin-errors and got this as the answer that resembles my situation: Scipy fmin argument passing
But it still doesn't work (the explicit notation of array, and args seem not to be the problem).
From 1 and 2 I deduce I cannot use a vector, from the other I don't understand the difference between a tuple and a list (I read that tuples are not modifiable, but I don't know why I have that). But I think it is rather in the 1 positional argument given instead of 2 (or 3) that is my real issue?
This is what I tried (and what I'd want is the minimum of that LogL function)

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "function") to tuple

q=vect_q
minimum = fmin(LogL,x0,q)


TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

q=vect_q
minimum = fmin(LogL,x0,(q[0],q[1]))


TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple

minimum = fmin(LogL,x0,args=q)


TypeError: LogL() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

minimum = fmin(LogL,x0,args=(q,))


TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple

minimum = fmin(LogL,x0,args=[MU,SIGMA])


TypeError: LogL() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

minimum = fmin(LogL,x0,(MU,SIGMA)) 


TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple

minimum = fmin(LogL,x0,args=(MU))


ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

minimum = fmin(LogL,x0,args=())

From other students, I got this solution:
def LogL(q):
    return -np.sum(np.log(normalpdf(data, q[0],q[1])))
minimum = fmin(LogL, [MU,SIGMA])

I'd like to know why it doesn't work for me, why that student seems to get a value rather than a function, and why it then can still get a minimum.

In python (3) is the same as 3.  (3,) makes a tuple. [3] makes a list.   The comma is important when writing a tuple.

When showing errors, we like to see the full traceback. It helps us (and YOU) identify where the error occurs.  Is it in the arguments, or in the evaluation of the function etc?

@hpaulj i have added the full traceback, however i cannot see it, but i see someone has changed my typos (maybe at the same time?) , could it be that my edit with the full errors is lost now?

The arguments are supposed to be a function, an intial condition array, and extra args tuple that gets passed as is to the function.  In q=vect_q, q is a function.  You can't subscript it.  Your x0 is one number.  That means fmin will varry one number and pass it to LogL.  Your LkgL is defined with one argument, so can't take any extras (args).

Read https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fit.html . I'm pretty sure that most of your code should be deleted, and you can just use fit() to get you an optimal log-likelihood.

hpaulj, ok so the value you pass as the initial x0 also goes to the function LogL (I thought it was just a starting point, but it makes sense that the starting point is passed to the function. If I understand it well, then I don't need any extra arguments at all, but my x0 should be an array of two numbers (since that is what LogL wants, and it works with the plot higher up  (which i have commented out, but it does plot LogL)
Then why does it refuse q in fmin (but accepts it in the plot? )
And why does it accept [MU,SIGMA] in the student's version but not in mine?

@Reinderien , you are absolutely right, but that is not the exercise I have to solve, I have to do it step by step

attaching edited version of your implementation.
Changes includes:

LogL must accept as inputs parameters that you optimize and then return single value that will be minimized. Basically you sum likelihoods for all the data:

def LogL(params):
    mu, sigma = params
    return  -np.log(normalpdf(data, mu, sigma)).sum()


to the fmin you should pass initial guess for the parameters in the x0 argument. Basically this is starting point for the vector x0 that is optimized:

mu0 = 0
sigma0 = 1
minimum = fmin(LogL, [mu0, sigma0])

Resulting code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.optimize import fsolve, fmin
from scipy.misc import derivative
from numpy import array

MU = 1.3
SIGMA = 4.5
N = 1000
N_BINS=20

data = np.random.normal(MU, SIGMA, N)
#print(data)

def normalpdf(x,mu,sigma): 
    return ((1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)))*(np.exp(-(((x-mu)**2))/(2*sigma**2))))

# plt.plot(data, normalpdf(data,MU,SIGMA),'.', color='purple')

def vect_q():
    q=[MU,SIGMA]
    return q

def LogL(params):
    mu, sigma = params

    return  -np.log(normalpdf(data, mu, sigma)).sum()

mu0 = 0
sigma0 = 1
q = vect_q()
minimum = fmin(LogL, [mu0, sigma0])
print(minimum)


@Johhny Cheesecutter, that is indeed a working program (same as the students version), but i don't understand why? I suppose

the LogL does not sum if i do =+ ?
the parameters in fmin don't work in mine, not because of the fmin but because of LogL?
and i still don't understand why LogL in your (or the student's) solution is not a function (i cannot plot it, but it does give me one single numerical value if i do a 'print the result') so how can it come up with a minimum? there must be something I don't understand about functions in python?


Yes, indeed your implementation of LogL returns a vector and not a single value. You can test it by passing random mu/sigma arguments

@Sarawara Why do you say LogL isn't a function? It is a function.

@jarred, In Johnny Cheesecutter's version I cannot  plot it, and I get 1 value if I do 'print (LogL([mu0,sigma0]))' So I don't understand how that can be a function (Even though the solution for the min is correct, so it must be, but i don't see how)

@Sarawara You don't seem to understand what a function is in Python. LogL is indeed a function and it is expected that LogL([mu0,sigma0]) returns a single float. As for why you can't plot it, I don't know what code you're using to try and plot it to say why it isn't working (but having an issue with plotting doesn't mean it's not a function). Your plotting issue is most likely related to not understanding that LogL doesn't accept vector (array) arguments.

@jared, I think indeed I don't fully understand how a function works in Python (but I've read everything I could find about it, done an edx course, read all the comments about arguments in functions. If you have documentation that explains how a function can be a function that doesn't give values for every y given an x but one single number, please do! (I've done C++ before, not the brightest admitted, but never felt as if I didn't understand functions there, maybe there are things to 'unlearn' ? I'm a 3rd year (adult) physics student, maybe i see it too much as a mathematical function?)

@Sarawara I'm not sure what "how a function can be a function that doesn't give values for every y given an x but one single number" means.

@jared, with:def LogL(q): mu, sigma = q return  -np.log(normalpdf(data, mu, sigma)).sum() . When I do : print (LogL([mu0,sigma0])) That print gives me a value, 1 value (namely: 11343.974004311836 ) , how can a function, only return 1 value when you give it a whole dataset for x? Why won't it give a value for each x?

@Sarawara Where are you giving it a whole dataset? You evaluated the function at a single point and it returned the value at that point. Your x here is [mu0,sigma0], which is a single input.

@jared, ah yes I see, I put square brackets!  A function can take parameters and act like a real function, or it can take a value and give the corresponding y-value. And what if I'd want to add all the y-values to get 1 number for a dataset of x's? I cannot use sum() in the same manner, cause i'd have a function like the log likelihood. I tried: for x in data: model=funct(data,parameters).sum() , but that gives me the same number all over.

And how could I plot the function? Because when I use a square bracket, it's a single value output and when I use curly brackets, it counts each value and I can have only 1 and if i do 'for x in data' it says it has not the same amount of y data (does it not give a new y for each x then?)

Your setup
In [1]: import numpy as np 
In [2]: from scipy.optimize import fsolve, fmin
   ...: from scipy.misc import derivative

In [3]: MU = 1.3
   ...: SIGMA = 4.5
   ...: N = 1000
   ...: N_BINS=20
   ...: 
   ...: data = np.random.normal(MU, SIGMA, N)

In [4]: data.shape
Out[4]: (1000,)

normalpdf runs with the right 3 arguments:
In [5]: def normalpdf(x,mu,sigma): 
   ...:     return ((1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)))*(np.exp(-(((x-mu)**2))/(2*sigma**2))))
   ...:     

In [6]: normalpdf(data,MU,SIGMA).shape
Out[6]: (1000,)


In [8]: def vect_q():
   ...:     q=[MU,SIGMA]
   ...:     return q
   ...: 
   ...: Logln=0
   ...: def LogL(q):
   ...:     return  Logln + (- np.log(normalpdf(data,q[0],q[1])))

vect_q is a function; vect_q() is a 2 element list produced by it:
In [10]: vect_q()
Out[10]: [1.3, 4.5]

In [11]: vect_q
Out[11]: <function __main__.vect_q()>

LogL runs with that 2 element list:
In [14]: res=LogL(vect_q())

In [15]: res.shape
Out[15]: (1000,)

In [16]: res[:10]
Out[16]: 
array([5.04359244, 2.49621998, 3.2011401 , 3.44538996, 2.6289669 ,
       2.66656073, 2.55164437, 2.56771704, 2.5617975 , 2.42495686])

first
I'm going leave most of the tracebacks in the display.  You should get used to trying to decipher them, even when long.
Your first fmin try fails because the function q is not subscriptable.  q() is a list and is subscriptable:
In [18]: x0 = 1
    ...: q=vect_q
    ...: minimum = fmin(LogL,x0,(q[0],q[1]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 3
      1 x0 = 1
      2 q=vect_q
----> 3 minimum = fmin(LogL,x0,(q[0],q[1]))

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

In [20]: q[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 1
----> 1 q[0]

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

second
In [21]: fmin(LogL,x0,q)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 1
----> 1 fmin(LogL,x0,q)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_optimize.py:695, in fmin(func, x0, args, xtol, ftol, maxiter, maxfun, full_output, disp, retall, callback, initial_simplex)
    586 """
    587 Minimize a function using the downhill simplex algorithm.
    588 
   (...)
    685 
    686 """
    687 opts = {'xatol': xtol,
    688         'fatol': ftol,
    689         'maxiter': maxiter,
   (...)
    692         'return_all': retall,
    693         'initial_simplex': initial_simplex}
--> 695 res = _minimize_neldermead(func, x0, args, callback=callback, **opts)
    696 if full_output:
    697     retlist = res['x'], res['fun'], res['nit'], res['nfev'], res['status']

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_optimize.py:845, in _minimize_neldermead(func, x0, args, callback, maxiter, maxfev, disp, return_all, initial_simplex, xatol, fatol, adaptive, bounds, **unknown_options)
    843 try:
    844     for k in range(N + 1):
--> 845         fsim[k] = func(sim[k])
    846 except _MaxFuncCallError:
    847     pass

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_optimize.py:569, in _wrap_scalar_function_maxfun_validation.<locals>.function_wrapper(x, *wrapper_args)
    567 ncalls[0] += 1
    568 # A copy of x is sent to the user function (gh13740)
--> 569 fx = function(np.copy(x), *(wrapper_args + args))
    570 # Ideally, we'd like to a have a true scalar returned from f(x). For
    571 # backwards-compatibility, also allow np.array([1.3]),
    572 # np.array([[1.3]]) etc.
    573 if not np.isscalar(fx):

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "function") to tuple

The error occurs deep in the fmin code, but basically it's trying to construct arguments for LogL from x0 and args:
fx = function(np.copy(x), *(wrapper_args + args))

Your args is q, a function.  I think wrapper_args is an empty tuple, so it's trying
In [23]: ()+q
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[23], line 1
----> 1 ()+q

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "function") to tuple

third
If we make args a tuple, containing the 2 element list:
In [27]: fmin(LogL,x0,args=(q(),))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 1
----> 1 fmin(LogL,x0,args=(q(),))

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_optimize.py:695, in fmin(func, x0, args, xtol, ftol, maxiter, maxfun, full_output, disp, retall, callback, initial_simplex)
    586 """
    587 Minimize a function using the downhill simplex algorithm.
    588 
   (...)
    685 
    686 """
    687 opts = {'xatol': xtol,
    688         'fatol': ftol,
    689         'maxiter': maxiter,
   (...)
    692         'return_all': retall,
    693         'initial_simplex': initial_simplex}
--> 695 res = _minimize_neldermead(func, x0, args, callback=callback, **opts)
    696 if full_output:
    697     retlist = res['x'], res['fun'], res['nit'], res['nfev'], res['status']

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_optimize.py:845, in _minimize_neldermead(func, x0, args, callback, maxiter, maxfev, disp, return_all, initial_simplex, xatol, fatol, adaptive, bounds, **unknown_options)
    843 try:
    844     for k in range(N + 1):
--> 845         fsim[k] = func(sim[k])
    846 except _MaxFuncCallError:
    847     pass

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_optimize.py:569, in _wrap_scalar_function_maxfun_validation.<locals>.function_wrapper(x, *wrapper_args)
    567 ncalls[0] += 1
    568 # A copy of x is sent to the user function (gh13740)
--> 569 fx = function(np.copy(x), *(wrapper_args + args))
    570 # Ideally, we'd like to a have a true scalar returned from f(x). For
    571 # backwards-compatibility, also allow np.array([1.3]),
    572 # np.array([[1.3]]) etc.
    573 if not np.isscalar(fx):

TypeError: LogL() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

The problem is LogL is defined as taking one argument, but we pass x0 plus the args element.
fourth
We could skip the args, and just pass q() list as the x0 initial value.  But now the problem is the LogL returns a 1000 element array, not a scalar value.
In [31]: fmin(LogL,q())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_optimize.py:575, in _wrap_scalar_function_maxfun_validation.<locals>.function_wrapper(x, *wrapper_args)
    574 try:
--> 575     fx = np.asarray(fx).item()
    576 except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:

ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[31], line 1
----> 1 fmin(LogL,q())

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_optimize.py:695, in fmin(func, x0, args, xtol, ftol, maxiter, maxfun, full_output, disp, retall, callback, initial_simplex)
    586 """
    587 Minimize a function using the downhill simplex algorithm.
    588 
   (...)
    685 
    686 """
    687 opts = {'xatol': xtol,
    688         'fatol': ftol,
    689         'maxiter': maxiter,
   (...)
    692         'return_all': retall,
    693         'initial_simplex': initial_simplex}
--> 695 res = _minimize_neldermead(func, x0, args, callback=callback, **opts)
    696 if full_output:
    697     retlist = res['x'], res['fun'], res['nit'], res['nfev'], res['status']

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_optimize.py:845, in _minimize_neldermead(func, x0, args, callback, maxiter, maxfev, disp, return_all, initial_simplex, xatol, fatol, adaptive, bounds, **unknown_options)
    843 try:
    844     for k in range(N + 1):
--> 845         fsim[k] = func(sim[k])
    846 except _MaxFuncCallError:
    847     pass

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_optimize.py:577, in _wrap_scalar_function_maxfun_validation.<locals>.function_wrapper(x, *wrapper_args)
    575         fx = np.asarray(fx).item()
    576     except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
--> 577         raise ValueError("The user-provided objective function "
    578                          "must return a scalar value.") from e
    579 return fx

ValueError: The user-provided objective function must return a scalar value.

In [32]: LogL(q()).shape
Out[32]: (1000,)

fifth
fmin(LogL,x0,args=[MU,SIGMA])

tries to call
LogL(x0, MU, SIGMA)

3 arguments when it should only be 1.
The 'float concatenate error is:
In [35]: ()+(MU)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[35], line 1
----> 1 ()+(MU)

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple

In [36]: (MU)
Out[36]: 1.3

In [37]: (MU,)
Out[37]: (1.3,)

A tuple has to have the comma.  (MU) is just MU.
This works:
def LogL(q):
    return -np.sum(np.log(normalpdf(data, q[0],q[1])))
minimum = fmin(LogL, [MU,SIGMA])

becaulse LogL returns a single number, which can be minimized.  [MU, SIGMA] is a valid starting point.

Wow, magnificent! Thank you very much hpaulj!
